# VSCode always use "C:\windows\System32\wsl.exe -e make" as make

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

for example, my tasks.json is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build",
            "command": "make",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Makefile is:

```
all:
    @echo $(shell uname)
```

The build output is "Linux". But it is a Windows Environment. I found my VSCode always use "C:\windows\System32\wsl.exe -e make" as make. I think it may have been a setting change a few years ago that caused the problem. But I cannot remember what was changed then.

I change the "command" in tasks.json as "C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe" like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build",
            "command": "C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

but the output is:

- The terminal process "C:\windows\System32\wsl.exe -e C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: If you did run the GnuWin32 build tools, you would no longer be creating a Linux binary. WSL is the correct thing here; it's how one gets from Windows into the Linux userland.

Comment: (GnuWin32 is more like cygwin; it's a Linuxy toolchain that creates Windows binaries).